# How do I quantify the difference in sample efficiency for two almost similar methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, policy-gradients

I am comparing my coded TD3 (Twin-Delayed DDPG) and the same TD3 (same hyperparameters) but with Priority Replay Buffer instead of a normal Replay Buffer.

From what I have read, PER (Priority Experience Replay, Priority Replay Buffer) aims to improve sample efficiency. But how do I measure or quantify sample efficiency on these two? Is it who gets the highest average reward in a given number of episodes? Does it have something to do with the batch size?

Comment: What is TD3 and PER? Please take the time to make your question clearer by providing further context.

Comment: @ThePointer I have already elaborated it